# Error in cluster.default(ID) : only implemented for resamples objects

Tags: cox-model, recurrent-events

I am trying to implement Andersen-Gill model for recurrent analysis. I wrote the following command

AG <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, status) ~ trt+size+number+cluster(id), data=bladder_AG.dat)

but I got the following error :
Error in cluster.default(id) : only implemented for resamples objects

can you please explain why I got this error and how I can get ride of it. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely an error due to having loaded both the `survival` and the `caret` packages at the same time. The caret function `cluster` will thus be dispatched instead of the `survival` one that is needed. It is however possible to directly specify the correct function and this should work:

```
library(survival)
library(caret)
AG <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, status) ~ trt +
              size +
              number +
              survival::cluster(id),
            data=bladder_AG.dat)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Fredrik Isaksson. You are exactly hit the problem. THANKS again